# Please explain this inner product equation

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

From Vladimir A. Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I, p. 431:

If a basis $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_m\}$ fixed in the space, then the inner product $\langle x,y \rangle$
of two vectors $x$ and $y$ can be expressed in terms of their coordinates $(x^1,\dotsc,x^m)$ and
 $(y^1,\dotsc,y^m)$ as the bilinear form 
$$\langle x,y \rangle=g_{ij}x^{i}y^{j}\tag{8.19}$$ 
(where summation over $i$ and $j$ is understood), in which $g_{ij}=\langle e_i,e_j \rangle$.

Please explain the Eq.(8.19), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

In conventional notation it is $$\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m g_{i,j} x^i y^j.$$
For example if $m=2$ then it is
$$g_{1,1} x^1 y^1 + g_{1,2} x^1 y^2 + g_{2,1} x^2 y^1 + g_{2,2} x^2 y^2.$$

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

According to the given choice of basis, the proposed relation results from the sesquilinearity of the inner product:
\begin{align*}
\langle x,y\rangle & = \langle x_{1}e_{1} + x_{2}e_{2} + \ldots + x_{n}e_{n},y_{1}e_{1} + y_{2}e_{2} + \ldots + y_{n}e_{n}\rangle\\\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\langle e_{i},y_{1}e_{1} + y_{2}e_{2} + \ldots + y_{n}e_{n}\rangle\\\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\overline{y}_{j}\langle e_{i},e_{j}\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{i}\overline{y}_{j}\langle e_{i},e_{j}\rangle
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by user1337 and angryavian's answer, and write the Eq. (8.19) in more detail:

By the properties
\begin{align}
\langle{}x,y\rangle&=\langle{}y,x\rangle,\\
\langle{}\lambda{}x,y\rangle&={\lambda}\langle{}x,y\rangle{\quad}\text{where }\lambda\in{}\mathbb{R},\\
\langle{}x+y,z\rangle&=\langle{}x,z\rangle+\langle{}y,z\rangle,\\
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
    x
&=x^{1}e_1+\dotsb+x^{m}e_m,{\ }y=y^{1}e_1+\dotsb+y^{m}e_m,\\
    \langle{}x,y\rangle
&=\langle{}x^{1}e_1+\dotsb+x^{m}e_m,{\ }y^{1}e_1+\dotsb+y^{m}e_m\rangle=\\
&=\langle{}x^{1}e_1,{\ }y^{1}e_1+\dotsb+y^{m}e_m\rangle+\dotsb+\\
&\phantom{={}}+\langle{}x^{m}e_m,{\ }y^{1}e_1+\dotsb+y^{m}e_m\rangle=\\
&=x^{1}\langle{}e_1,{\ }y^{1}e_1+\dotsb+y^{m}e_m\rangle+\dotsb+\\
&\phantom{={}}+x^{m}\langle{}e_m,{\ }y^{1}e_1+\dotsb+y^{m}e_m\rangle=\\
&=x^{1}\Big(y^{1}\langle{}e_1,{\ }e_1\rangle+\dotsb+y^{m}\langle{}e_1,{\ }e_m\rangle\Big)+\dotsb+\\
&\phantom{={}}+x^{m}\Big(y^{1}\langle{}e_m,{\ }e_1\rangle+\dotsb+y^{m}\langle{}e_m,{\ }e_m\rangle\Big)=\\
&=\Big(x^{1}y^{1}\langle{}e_1,{\ }e_1\rangle+\dotsb+x^{1}y^{m}\langle{}e_1,{\ }e_m\rangle\Big)+\dotsb+\\
&\phantom{={}}+\Big(x^{m}y^{1}\langle{}e_m,{\ }e_1\rangle+\dotsb+x^{m}y^{m}\langle{}e_m,{\ }e_m\rangle\Big)=\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m}x^{i}y^{j}\langle{}e_i,{\ }e_j\rangle=g_{ij}x^{i}y^{j}.
\end{align}